# Can't get JSON string to parse into an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using the following PHP code to return a json string:

```
$itemURL = 'http://***.***.***/search?tag=Football&affiliate_id=&max_results=3';
$response = file_get_contents($itemURL);//curl_exec($curlHandle);
echo $response;
$response = array($response);
echo $response[0];
```

I get a json string that looks something like this:

> [
>       {
>           "ID": "123",
>           "Description": "Champion Football Navy T-shirt",
>           "HighPrice": 16.99,
>           "LowPrice": 16.99,
>           "SalePrice": null,
>           "OnSale": false,
>           "URL": "http://www.mystore.com/itemDescription",
>           "ImageURL": "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg",
>           "LargeImageURL": "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg",
>           "ThumbnailImageURL": "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg",
>           "MiniImageURL": "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg",
>           "AffiliateID": ""
>       },
>       {
>           "ID": "23",
>           "Description": "Champion Football Navy T-shirt XL",
>           "HighPrice": 16.99,
>           "LowPrice": 16.99,
>           "SalePrice": null,
>           "OnSale": false,
>           "URL": "http://www.mystore.com/itemDescription",
>           "ImageURL": "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg",
>           "LargeImageURL": "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg",
>           "ThumbnailImageURL": "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg",
>           "MiniImageURL": "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg",
>           "AffiliateID": ""
>       }
>   ]

However when I echo $response[0] I get the entire string. If I use json_decode or encode I get a string but with quotes around it. I can't figure out how to cast this dang thing so it operates as an array of objects that I can then iterate through. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: `json_decode($response)` (placed right after it is set from `file_get_contents`) does not return an object?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this not a legit question? It's a problem I'm having, I couldn't find the answer on google or here, and I provided my source code, and the json I was working with. I don't get why I was voted down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$itemURL = 'http://***.***.***/search?tag=Football&affiliate_id=&max_results=3';
$response = file_get_contents($itemURL);//curl_exec($curlHandle);
$response = json_decode($response);
```

You'll get an object like...

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (12) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(3) "123"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(30) "Champion Football Navy T-shirt"
    ["HighPrice"]=>
    float(16.99)
    ["LowPrice"]=>
    float(16.99)
    ["SalePrice"]=>
    NULL
    ["OnSale"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["URL"]=>
    string(38) "http://www.mystore.com/itemDescription"
    ["ImageURL"]=>
    string(40) "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg"
    ["LargeImageURL"]=>
    string(40) "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg"
    ["ThumbnailImageURL"]=>
    string(40) "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg"
    ["MiniImageURL"]=>
    string(40) "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg"
    ["AffiliateID"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (12) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(2) "23"
    ["Description"]=>
    string(33) "Champion Football Navy T-shirt XL"
    ["HighPrice"]=>
    float(16.99)
    ["LowPrice"]=>
    float(16.99)
    ["SalePrice"]=>
    NULL
    ["OnSale"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["URL"]=>
    string(38) "http://www.mystore.com/itemDescription"
    ["ImageURL"]=>
    string(40) "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg"
    ["LargeImageURL"]=>
    string(40) "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg"
    ["ThumbnailImageURL"]=>
    string(40) "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg"
    ["MiniImageURL"]=>
    string(40) "http://www.mystore.com/mainstore/045.jpg"
    ["AffiliateID"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

And then you can access your JSON objects using $response[0], $response[1], etc... Using the specific name of the field like **$response[0]->AffiliateID** for istance.

Comment: I think the problem I was having was with the syntax of $response[0]->AffiliateID. I couldn't figure out what the right syntax was. Thanks for the help you have saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the property you are looking for

IE:

```
echo response[0].ID; //getting the 1st item in the response array then access the "ID" property of the json object.
```

The json response is a dynamic object that allows you to interact with all the properties as though you created the object from scratch.

The values inside the [{... and the ... }] are the object values.

so...

```
var json = '{"ID" : 1, "Prop1" : "Value1", Prop2 : "Value2" }';
```

can be parsed using jQuery's parseJSON method

```
var obj= jQuery.parseJSON(json);
echo obj.ID; //1
echo obj.Prop1; //Value
echo obj.Prop2; //Value2
```

When you have the [... and ...] around the { and } you know this object is an array and needs to be treated accordingly.

Hope this helps.

wm

Comment: I gave you an upvote for the help, but it was a php question not javascript. Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$response["events"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $tmparr = array();
        $tmparr["uid"] = $row["uid"];
        $tmparr["date"] = $row["date"];
        $tmparr["hours"] = $row["hours"];
        $tmparr["store_name"] = $row["store_name"];
        $tmparr["event_information"] = $row["event_information"];
        $tmparr["event_type"] = $row["event_type"];
        $tmparr["Phone"] = $row["Phone"];
        $tmparr["price"] = $row["price"];
        $tmparr["address"] = $row["address"];
        $tmparr["image_url"] = $row["image_url"];
        $tmparr["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $tmparr["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];
        array_push($response["events"], $tmparr);
}    
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
```

I can't understand what you are trying to do but This is the way that i use in order to return an array of rows of data from a sql query ($result). I hope this helps you

Comment: This part of the process is fixed so I can't change it. The problem I was having was with the json that was being sent. Actually the problem was with the syntax of trying to access that information. But it's all good now.